# Stuck at failure configuring windows updates

Tags: windows-8

I chose "Update and Restart" from the Windows 8 menu and after installing 135 update items, a message appears on the screen saying

Failure configuring Windows updates. Reverting changes. Do not turn off your computer.

This screens persist for 30-45 minutes then the computer restarts to the HP loading screen then the screen appears again. Afterwards, the computer restarts then immediately shuts down with the power lights still on and fan at full speed but nothing else. I cannot log into the computer as the computer keeps shutting down.

**UPDATE**

The loop have ended and i was able to log in successfully. However, my computer will frequently shuts down while i was working with the symptoms described above (fan at full speed, power light on)

Comment: do you get a BSOD now? Look in the event logs for details.

Comment: No. I can log it and do my own things but it will just sguts down without warning after a while

Comment: look in the eventlog for details. If you see kernel error 41, check this KB article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2028504

Answer (score 1):

Please boot from the Windows 8 DVD or [Windows Recovery Environment](https://www.terabyteunlimited.com/kb/article.php?id=322) and run the command prompt in the repair options and run this:

```
DISM /image:C:\ /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions /ScratchDir:C:\
```

*(replace C: with the drive where you installed Windows 8)*

This reverts all pending operations. Now you should go back to Windows 8.

Now copy the folder C:\Windows\logs\CBS to your desktop, zip it, upload it to OneDrive, create a share link and post the link here. I'll take a look what is causing the loop.

Comment: please read the update

Answer (score -1):

When you try to install Windows updates, you get the following error:
Failure configuring Windows updates. Reverting changes. Do not turn off your computer.

Note If this issue occurs, it may take about 30 minutes to revert the changes, and then the system will show the Windows logon screen.
To resolve this issue, use the following methods starting with the first method below. If that doesn't resolve your issue, click next method.
Restart your computer (Windows 8 only)

To restart Windows 8, follow these steps:
Swipe from the upper-right corner of the screen (or if you're using a mouse, move your pointer to the upper-right hand corner of the screen), and then tap or click Settings.
Tap or click Power, and then tap or click Restart.
Try to install Windows Updates again.
Unplug your removable media from the computer (Windows 8, Windows 7, and Windows Vista)

You have to unplug all your removable media from the computer, such as removable disks (Blu-ray disks, DVDs, CDs), memory cards (CompactFlash card, Secure Digital card, Memory Stick), and USB flash drives.

These removable media may cause this issue during the restart of Windows.
Run the Windows Update Troubleshooter (Windows 8, Windows 7, and Windows Vista)

Windows 8 or Windows 7

To download and run the Windows Update troubleshooter, click the run now button below, or you can open it by following the steps below:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/949358

Comment: i cannot log in to the computer let alone shut it down or restart

Comment: What portion of this answer is your words and what portion of this answer is from the support article.  I should point out, I know the answer to this question, I am asking you to update the question to make that clear.

Comment: The only difference between the situation in the support article and my situation is the fact that i cannot login to the computer to do any of the instructions listed